# Python Recursion error

Tags: python, recursion

Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work?

I am trying to create a change machine using recursion. The first parameter is the amount of change that we need to give back, and the second parameter is an array of the number of bills with the first element representing $25, the second representing $50 and the last 
representing $100.

When I call `checkchange(125,[0,1,1])` it now does not return "T" or "F"
instead it just prints out 
`lets go
Bills: 011 Money: 125
ok the money is greater than 100
lets go
Bills: 010 Money: 25
this is the money 25`

Here is the code:

```
def checkchange(money,bills):
     tot = bills[0] * 25 + bills[1] * 50 + bills[2] * 100
     print("lets go")    
     string = "".join(str(e) for e in bills)
     print("Bills: %s Money %d" % (string,money))
     if tot < money:
         return "F"



     elif money == 25 and bills[0] == 0:
         return "F"


     elif money >= 100 and bills[2] > 0:
         print("ok the money is greater than 100")
         money -= 100
         bills[2] -= 1
         checkchange(money,bills)
         print("this is the money %d" % money)
     elif money >= 50 and bills[1] > 0:
         print("ok the money is greater than 50")
         money -= 50
         bills[1] -= 1
         checkchange(money,bills)
     elif money >= 25 and bills[0] > 0:
         print("money is greater than 25")
         money -= 25
         bills[0] -=1 
         checkchange(money,bills)
     else: 
         return "T"
```

Comment: Use `and`, not `&`

Comment: Please add input data and the expected outcome or provide a error message if any.

Comment: @ppasler just added the expected outcome

Comment: Why do you use "T" and "F" instead of the built-in booleans? What is the boolean output of the function supposed to represent?

Comment: I just wanted to return a string, this function is part of another function that accepts a string

Comment: For some reason it does not reach the other conditional logic whenever I call the function  **only** "lets go" is printed.

Comment: Maybe you give some more inputs and the expected outcome.

Answer (score 3):

The ampersand `&` in Python is the [`bitwise AND`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operator.  It's not the same as the boolean `and` operator. When you have a statement like

```
if money == 25 & bills[0] == 0:
```

That's actually being read as `money == (25 & bills[0]) == 0`, because `&` binds more tightly than `==`.  [Here's a useful chart](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) on operator precedence

Comment: OK thanks for an explanation and the information on the operator precedence , I'll see if it works!

Answer (score 2):

I assume the condition is wrong `tot > money` should be `!=`.

```
 def checkchange(money,bills):
      tot = bills[0] * 25 + bills[1] * 50 + bills[2] * 100
      print("lets go")    
      if tot != money:
          return "F"

      if money == 25 and bills[0] == 0:
          return "F"


      if money >= 100 and bills[2] > 0:
          print("ok the money is greater than 100")
          money -= 100
          bills[2] -= 1
          checkchange(money,bills)
          print("this is the money %d" % money)
      if money >= 50 and bills[1] > 0:
          print("ok the money is greater than 50")
          money -= 50
          bills[1] -= 1
          checkchange(money,bills)
      if money >= 25 and bills[0] > 0:
          print("money is greater than 25")
          money -= 25
          bills[0] -=1 
          checkchange(money,bills)

      return "T"

 print checkchange(125,[1,0,1])
 print checkchange(125,[0,1,1])
```

Outcome:

```
 lets go
 ok the money is greater than 100
 lets go
 money is greater than 25
 lets go
 this is the money 25
 T
 lets go
 F
```

Comment: Can you include the output of those two prints at the bottom please?

Comment: If this is it, you can accept the answer and close the question.

Comment: Thanks but this is not exactly what I am going for in the program. The total amount of money can be unequal to the money needed to give out, it is like the total cash in the cash register, the _money_ variable is the money that is needed to be given out.

Comment: I see, than comment whats wrong and we see how to fix it